# Swift POST to api

Tags: swift

I have an odd issue and I am hoping you guys can help me.

The Task:
I want to post json to a API rest call.

And I am sure the rest API works - I have copied the json from print() in Swift and tried it in postman, and the works just fine.

When I try to post via Swift i get 400 Bad request.
The code:

```
   func postMobileContacts(serverURL: String, jsonToPost: String){
    
    // Prepare URL
    let url = URL(string: serverURL)
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    // Prepare URL Request Object
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
     
    // Set HTTP Request Body
    request.httpBody = Data(jsonToPost.utf8);
    
    
    // Set HTTP Request Header
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: String(data: KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: "access-token", account: "store")!, encoding: .utf8)!)
    // Perform HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
     
            // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
            }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending jsonToPost parameter as String rather than [String: Any] if it is a JSON?

Comment: Great question - I am converting it from a object before I call the function and my code from object to json looks like this:
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(contactsToExport)
let json = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

Comment: Could you try sending request.httpBody = jsonData , instead of converting object to Data to String and then to Data again. That is not necessary

Comment: Did you know that POSTMAN can generate Swift URL Session code? Not beautiful Swift code, but working one, and it might help you spot the difference. Also, it can generate a `cURL` command, that you could share, and it will help us see the difference. But currently, we can't guess the issue. Except your strange way of passing body data...

Comment: I Agree to @Larme. May be you should also add your request object model also to the above. Issue might be with the datatype of any of the members in that model.

Comment: Thank you guys - Burnsi spotted the error.

@Larme thanks for the POSTMAN trick, that it super smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is definitely wrong:

```
request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: String(data: KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: "access-token", account: "store")!, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

it should be the other way around.

```
request.setValue(String(data: KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: "access-token", account: "store")!, encoding: .utf8)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

You mixed up the value with the header name.

Comment: Well spotted, Burnsi!
That did the it and it work's now

Answer (score 0):

Made some edits to your code

Currently the data is not directly sent to the request as said in comments.
*JSONEncodable* can be send to the request after encoding to data.

```
    func postMobileContacts(serverURL: String, jsonToPost: Encodable) { //<--here
        
        // Prepare URL
        let url = URL(string: serverURL)
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(jsonToPost) //<-Changed here
        
        // Prepare URL Request Object
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
         
        // Set HTTP Request Body
        request.httpBody = data;  //<-- and here
   
        
        // Set HTTP Request Header
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: String(data: KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: "access-token", account: "store")!, encoding: .utf8)!)
        // Perform HTTP Request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error took place \(error)")
                    return
                }
         
                // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
                }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Sadly I get the same error:
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>